# Invalid EVM version requested & Error: Truffle is currently using solc 0.5.0

Tags: truffle

I'm starting to learn solidity with Dapp University guide on youtube, and as soon as 20th minute of this guide I'm running into problem with Truffle compiling.

I cloned this repository:
`git clone -b starter-code https://github.com/dappuniversity/defi_tutorial ./`
And this is YT link to this tutorial:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CgXQC4dbGUE

Truffle config on this guide looks like this:

```js
require('babel-register');
require('babel-polyfill');

module.exports = {
  networks: {
    development: {
      host: "127.0.0.1",
      port: 7545,
      network_id: "*" // Match any network id
    },
  },
  contracts_directory: './src/contracts/',
  contracts_build_directory: './src/abis/',
  compilers: {
    solc: {
      optimizer: {
        enabled: true,
        runs: 200
      },
      evmVersion: "petersburg"
    }
  }
}
```

And at this point in the guide, compiling succeeds, but I get an error:

```
Error: Truffle is currently using solc 0.5.16, but one or more of your contracts specify "pragma solidity ^0.5.0
```

So I went to Truffle documentation, I found that I can specify solc version in the config, so I added `version`field, and my config looks now like this:

```js
// ...
compilers: {
    solc: {
      version: "0.5.0",
      optimizer: {
        enabled: true,
        runs: 200
      },
      evmVersion: "petersburg"
    }
  }
// ...
```

And again my compiling failed, with another error but this time with `evmVersion`:

```
Invalid EVM version requested.

Compilation failed. See above.
Truffle v5.1.39 (core: 5.1.39)
Node v16.9.1
```

Now I've change EVM version from `"petersburg"` to `"byzantium"` and I'm getting to another Compilation Faild with error:
`Error: Truffle is currently using solc 0.5.0, but one or more of your contracts specify "pragma solidity ^0.5.0`

Can someone provide me some knowledge how to deal with this error?

Comment: Try to comment out the "evmVersion" and compile your project or  change it to antoher version like "byzantium" for ex.

Comment: I have updated this post, I've change to "byzantium" and I'm getting other error. 
Commenting out "evmVersion" gives the same result.
And without ```version: "0.5.0"``` error is the same but saying about other solc version on truffle: ```Error: Truffle is currently using solc 0.5.16```

Comment: If you right-click inside a solidity contract, you will have a couple of options to chose from including "Change global compile version". Once you click on it, you will see a list of solidity versions. Click on the one you need(0.5.0) and it should work.

Comment: Probably it worked.. I dont't know yet, cause I'm running into next errors, but this time: ```ParserError: Expected ';' but got '}'``` or ```ParserError: Expected ';' but got end of source``` depends on where I put ";" as I don't know much about syntax yet, etc. So I guess it's for different thread.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

changing the EVM version from "petersburg" to "byzantium" and the compiler version to "0.5.0" worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

You need to download the compiler version needed, or change contract solidity version.

Comment: How can I know which compiler version is needed in this case?
You mean update Truffle?

Answer (score 0):

Change the config at truffle-config.js to your contract solidity version